# What is the most elegant or Pythonic way to initialise a Django object?

Tags: python, django, object, initialization

I am new to Python and Django but feel like there must be a neater way of accomplishing this than I have found.

I have a Django model that has a date attribute with a non-trivial default value, meaning that I need a little bit of logic to set it up.  I have tried several ways of doing this, but unfortunately this is the only one that has worked for me so far (in `models.py` within a `weeks` app):

```
def first_day_of_next_week():
    return timezone.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=timezone.now().date().weekday() +
        datetime.timedelta(days=7)

class Week(models.model):
    start_of_week = models.Datefield('Date of the first day of the week',
        unique=True, default=first_day_of_next_week())
```

I strongly dislike having a function floating outside of any class like that (but don't have the experience to know whether it is actually bad).  I have tried incorporating it into a static or class method, or within an `__init__` process within Week, but can't get any of those approaches to work properly (in particular, Django seems to complicate hijacking `__init__`).

Now that I have the Week model working, I want to instantiate weeks with `Week.objects.get_or_create()` from `views.py`, but here I hit the problem that I need the same `first_day_of_next_week()` logic to be accessible within `views.py`.  (This is what pushed me to try moving the logic over to a static or class method that could be accessed from `views.py`.)  I can copy-paste `first_day_of_next_week()` into `views.py`, and it works, but that feels wrong for all sorts of reasons.  I suppose I could have no default and keep the logic for creating a Week only in `views.py`, but I am under the impression that it is preferable to have all Week-related logic in the model wherever possible.

What would an experienced Python programmer do?

Comment: "I strongly dislike having a function floating outside of any class like that (but don't have the experience to know whether it is actually bad). " It isn't bad. It's perfectly normal. Functions that don't require access to internal class state *should not be members of the class*

Comment: I've answered to the question in the title of the post, but your question isn't actually about it, but about the architecture. To understand how to organize your code you need to learn what architecture layers are, and how to organize your code in layers. I can only recommend to read some books. There's one i like https://github.com/cosmicpython/book.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, that is a useful pointer, but don't all static methods fit that criterion?

Comment: @Dan yes, I would agree, `staticmethod` is pretty pointless, and almost always would just be better as a module-level function. Sometimes, they are nice as a tool for code organization / API design.... But In most of the code I've written in Python, for the past 4 years professionally, I've included maybe one or two  staticmethod's

Answer (score 0):

Django models are still python classes. You can use `__init__` for initialization, as it meant to be by python:

```py
def first_day_of_next_week():
    return timezone.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(
        days=timezone.now().date().weekday() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    )


class Week(models.model):
    start_of_week = models.DateField(
        'Date of the first day of the week', unique=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_of_week = self.start_of_week or first_day_of_next_week()
```

I also recommend do this instead of using `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` DateField, DateTimeField keywords, since otherwise you will not be able to pass your own values to these fields in tests, django will override your values during db save.